# Better way to approximate the square root using exhaustive enumeration?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the best way I have found, using the least processor:

```
x = 25
epsilon = 0.001
step = epsilon**2
numGuesses = 0
ans = 0.0
while abs(ans**2 - x) > epsilon and ans <=x:
    ans += step
    numGuesses += 1
print 'numGuesses =', numGuesses
if abs(ans**2 - x) >= epsilon:
    print 'Failed on square root of number', x
else:
    print ans, 'is close to square root of', x
```

for numbers greater one

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: that isn't python 3 code.  and why are you bothering to do this in python instead of just taking a square root?

Comment: @Eevee he might need to build the square root from scratch, this is mathematically still open problem, if you ask any math-programmer how to find a square root of a number, you might have diff options. But he still need to show clear question so we can help

Answer (score 2):

What about using the [`math.sqrt`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.sqrt) method.

If it is however more a question on how to calculate the square root algorithmically, you might consider *binary search*. Such binary search could use two stages:

- a stage to find an upper bound; and
- a stage to use binary search to determine the exact value

Or a well known algorithm that is in many cases used in exercises in electrical engineering is *Newton's method*, you can use the convergence sequence:

```
x(i+1) = 0.5*[x(i)+y/x(i)]
```

In python, you could implement this as:

```
x = 25
numGuesses = 0
ans = 1.0
for i in range(0, 5):
    ans = 0.5*(ans+x/ans)
    numGuesses += 1
```

Where `5` is an arbitrary number to converge to enough precision.

But for performance reasons, `math.sqrt` is the best option since it is processed on the floating-point coprocessor (thus hardware). In case you need to determine the square root more accurate you could define your own floating-point and implement one of these methods. For many applications however, the default floating-point and its operations are sufficient.

Comment: Just adding to this clear answer a link to the different methods that the author pointed to, check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots

Comment: Newton's method converges quadratically, so 20 iterations may even be somewhat excessive.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I agree, modified to `5`. But I think one better uses the floating point sqrt anyway. Only if you want extreme high precision, you can use a custom algorithm, but in that case you should first design a floating point with higher precision.